# Unable to import speech services

Tags: python, azure

I am going through the Microsoft Learn lesson regarding Speech Cognitive services located here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/transcribe-speech-input-text/5-exercise-convert-speech-from-audio-file?pivots=python

My issue is that I am unable to import azure.cognitiveservices.speech.

If I run this one line "import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk" I get the error:

```
PS C:\Users\bianca\OneDrive\Documents\Azure\Projects\MicrosoftLearn> & "C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe" c:/Users/bianc/OneDrive/Documents/Azure/Projects/MicrosoftLearn/.vscode/speechtotext.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bianca\OneDrive\Documents\Azure\Projects\MicrosoftLearn\.vscode\speechtotext.py", line 1, in <module>
    import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices.speech'
```

I have tried installing cognitive speech services through CMD using “pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech” and I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-cognitiveservices-speech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for azure-cognitiveservices-speech
```

Just to see if another package would install, I tried C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts>pip install azure-cognitiveservices-language-spellcheck which worked without issue.

I went to https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html and the Speech SDK is not listed.

Python version 3.9 for win64 |
Visual Studio Code 1.51.1 |
Computer is  Win10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `azure-cognitiveservices-speech` currently only supports python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the SPEECH SDK is supported in Python 3.5 to 3.8, hence the error (& 64 Bit)

[image]

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?tabs=dotnet%2Cwindows%2Cjre%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-python

**OS Requirement**

- Windows: x64 and x86
- Mac: macOS X version 10.12 or later
- Linux based as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk?tabs=windows%2Cubuntu%2Cios-xcode%2Cmac-xcode%2Candroid-studio)

You could refer the above article for the other requirements to run the SDK.

You could download Python Specific version from https://www.python.org/downloads/

[image]

Comment: Pls consider accepting the answer if it had helped.